# Scrapy + Selenium 302 redirection handling

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I'm building a webcrawler that logs into my bank account and gathers data about my spending. I originally was going to use only Scrapy but it didn't work since the First Merit page uses Javascript to log in so I piled Selenium on top.

My code logs in (first you need to input username, and then password, not in conjunction as in most pages) through a series of yielding Requests with specific callback functions that handle the next step.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import selenium
import time


class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'www.firstmerit.com'
   # allowed_domains = ['https://www.firstmeritib.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.firstmeritib.com/AccountHistory.aspx?a=1']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        # Obtaining necessary components to input my own stuff
        username = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtUsername"]'))
        login_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnLogin"]'))

        # The actual interaction
        username.send_keys("username")
        login_button.click()

        # The process of logging in is broken up in two functions since the website requires me
        # to enter my username first which redirects me to a password page where I cna finally enter my account (after inputting password)
        yield Request(url = self.driver.current_url,
                      callback = self.password_handling,
                       meta = {'dont_redirect' : True,
                               'handle_httpstatus_list': [302],
                               'cookiejar' : response}
        )


    def password_handling(self, response):

        print("^^^^^^")
        print(response.url)

        password = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainContent_txtPassword"]'))
        login_button2 = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(lambda driver: self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainContent_btnLogin"]'))

        password.send_keys("password")
        login_button2.click()

        print("*****")
        print(self.driver.current_url)
        print("*****")

        yield Request (url = self.driver.current_url,
                       callback = self.after_login, #, dont_filter = True,
                       meta = {'dont_redirect' : True,
                               'handle_httpstatus_list': [302],
                               'cookiejar' : response.meta['cookiejar'] }
                       )

    def after_login(self, response):
        print"***"
        print(response.url)
        print"***"

        print(response.body)

        if "Account Activity" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return
        else:
            print("you got through!")
            print()
```

The issue is that once I finally get to my account page where all my spending is displayed, I can't actually access the HTML data. I've properly handles 302 redirections, but the "meta = " options seem to take me to the page through selenium, but don't let me scrape it.

Instead of getting all the data from response.body in the after_login function, I get the following:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Default.aspx?ReturnURL=%2fAccountHistory.aspx%3fa%3d1">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

How do I manage to actually be able to get that information to scrape it? 
Is this redirection in place by the bank to protect account from being crawled?
Thank you!